# Function [function signature] Statement is not valid in a namespace

Tags: vb.net

I get 2 errors on the following statements when making a keygenerator for XP Repair Pro6:

1. `TextBox2.Text = Generate(Strings.LCase(TextBox1.Text), Strings.LCase(MD5("xprp6-K0Wc0kf3Wcm5g-FEe43f")))`

   > 'MD5' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.
2. `Public Shared Function MD5(ByVal InputStr As String) As String`

   > Statement is not valid in a namespace.

How do I fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: actually i don't know how to do that,, i'm sorta newbie on that programming language, help from you will be sppreciated

Comment: But wait, you have errors at lines 70 and 74. Show those lines (and probably some more, too)

Comment: @YakovL the two lines causing the errors *are* in the OP... and the errors are pretty self-explanatory too.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). If you are copying code which is indented a long way (in Visual Studio - other IDEs may be the same), you can get a cleaner copy by holding down the Alt key when selecting the code (it creates a rectangular selection instead of line-by-line-with-all-the-indenting).

Answer (score 0):

You defined your `MD5` function in a namespace, and that's not valid; functions must be in a `Module` or `Class` scope; it's modules and classes that live in namespaces, not functions.

In other words, you have this:

```
Namespace Some.Namespace

    Class Foo
        '...code...
    End Class

    Public Shared Function MD5(ByVal InputStr As String) As String
         '...code...
    End Function

End Namespace
```

And you need to have this:

```
Namespace Some.Namespace

    Class Foo

        '...code...

        Public Shared Function MD5(ByVal InputStr As String) As String
             '...code...
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: can you please send me how it goes in writing, as i said i'm newbie here and still learning for a school project and i need help please, thanks

Comment: well, i was following this youtube tut step by step without mistakes, and i was doing it step by step even i have the same software versions on the video he has, here is the link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D5FOPOkE5Y

Comment: define "not working" - I doubt you're still getting the same compile error that brought you here. if that's the case, then *this question* is answered.

Comment: Please check the both photos of both errors (https://www.pinterest.com/pin/295971006745330448) + (https://www.pinterest.com/pin/295971006745330442)

Thanks in advance ans sorry for bothering you

Comment: I'm really so sorry sir and i know you don't have to bear with me, though i'm a newbie and i need this help very much, and i appreciate your help and reply no matter what!!

Comment: @RodrikEddardStark : If you read his answer thoroughly and compare the differences between _"you have this"_ and _"you need to have this"_ you have a complete solution.